# Jsoup select li from ul

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to select from following ul **all** children with Jsoup.

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs xlarge-12 columns hide-for-small-only">

<li>
<a href="http://www.thalia.de/shop/home/show/">
Home
</a>

</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.thalia.de/shop/buecher/show/">
B&uuml;cher
</a>

</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.thalia.de/shop/fachbuecher-115/show/">
Fachb&uuml;cher
</a>

</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.thalia.de/shop/chemie-143/show/">
Chemie
</a>

</li>

</ul>
```

Here is my code, but this gives me only the first two elements. What am I doing wrong?

```
Elements category = doc.select("div.ncMain.productMainView");
Elements category2 = category.select("ul.breadcrumbs.xlarge-12.columns.hide-for-small-only");
Elements category3 = category2.select("ul li a");
String categoryString = category3.text();
```

Comment: I've just tried your exact code with the latest Jsoup and it worked fine.

Comment: also with this source code? view-source:http://www.thalia.de/shop/chemie-143/rubrikartikel/chemie/charles_e_mortimer/EAN9783134843125/ID42803321.html

Comment: No, but in that page for your selector, there really is only to `li`s. Even visually, you can see only to items in that menu. In Chrome dev tools, if Ctrl+F in the Elements tab, you search by CSS, and typing `div.ncMain.productMainView ul.breadcrumbs.xlarge-12.columns.hide-for-small-only` will show you the menu.

Comment: Try to set your `userAgent` string - maybe you are getting different responses for the browser and your app.

Comment: @TDG as kaqqao pointed out, the displayed `li` elements are not present, when you reach the site for the first time. It seems to depend on prior browsing the website and resulting jsession if the additional categories are listed.